# Nan/Undefined number attribute

Tags: javascript

The short of it is that I'm trying to create a Snake JS implementation. To do the "bending" part of the game, I've opted to use "turning points" to keep track of when a snake needs to change course. To track the point and direction, I used an object called turnPoint:

```
var turnPoint = {x: 0, y: 0, direction: 0};
```

This is for a class I'm teaching beginning programming. Not sure why adding the turnPoint.x and turnPoint.y throws an undefined exception. When I wrap with the Number() func, I get a Nan. Is this a prototyping problem?

Full source code is over at [GitHub](http://www.github.com/roguequery/snakeJS)

```
var turns = new Array();

function move(key){
    if(lastKeyPressed == null){
        lastKeyPressed = currentKey;
    }
    var delta = moveRate;
    if(currentKey == leftArrow || currentKey == upArrow){
        delta *= -1;
    }

    //only change direction if the key isn't the same, and not the opposite key up vs down, left vs right
    if(currentKey != lastKeyPressed && Math.abs(lastKeyPressed-currentKey) != 2){
        //lets create a container to hold the turning point
        var turnPoint = {x: 0, y: 0, direction: 0};

        if(lastKeyPressed == leftArrow || currentKey == leftArrow) //from left, going up or down
        {
            turnPoint = {x: Number(snakePoints[0]), y: Number(snakePoints[1]), direction: currentKey};
        }else if(lastKeyPressed == rightArrow || currentKey == rightArrow)
        {
            turnPoint = {x: Number(snakePoints[2]), y: Number(snakePoints[3]), direction:currentKey};
        }

        if(turnPoint != null){
            turns.push(turnPoint);
            console.log(turns);
        }
    }


    if(currentKey == leftArrow){
        snakePoints[0] += delta;
    }else if(currentKey == rightArrow){
        snakePoints[2] += delta;
    }else if(currentKey == upArrow){
        snakePoints[1] += delta;
    }else{
        snakePoints[3] += delta;
    }
    var newLine = new Array();

    newLine.push(snakePoints[0]);
    newLine.push(snakePoints[1]);

    for(var turn in turns){
        newLine.push(Number(turn.x));
        newLine.push(Number(turn.y));
    }

    newLine.push(snakePoints[2]);
    newLine.push(snakePoints[3]);

    console.log(newLine);

    lastKeyPressed = currentKey;
    snake.setPoints(newLine);
    drawGame();
}
```

Comment: For clarification, the term JSON really isn't appropriate for that. It's just an object.

Comment: right, but the syntax of the object is JSON compliant right?

Comment: Also you haven't said where exactly you get that exception. If one of your beginning programming students came to you and said, "I get an exception", wouldn't that be the first thing you asked?

Comment: @roguequery No, keys in JSON Objects need to be in quotes and you still wouldn't call it JSON unless the whole thing is in a string like `'{"x": 0, "y": 0, "direction": 0}'`

Comment: No, in this case it is definitely not JSON. JSON syntax requires both property names and string values to be quoted with double quotes. That's *allowed* in JavaScript object literal syntax, but not required.

Comment: Something is wrong with your `snakePoints`.

Comment: sorry, it happens after i try to put the turnPoints coordinates into the snakePoint array and the console.log shows undefined/Nan

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` loops for arrays!  Always use a numeric index.

Comment: @Paulpro good to know, I'll fix that and maybe that fixes it. snakePoints is defined near the beginning of the js file. this isn't the full source as thats a lot of code not pertinent to the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var turn in turns){
    newLine.push(Number(turn.x));
    newLine.push(Number(turn.y));
}
```

In JavaScript, a `for ... in` loop iterates through the property **names** of an object, not the property **values**.

```
for (var i = 0; i < turns.length; ++i) {
  newLine.push(Number(turns[i].x));
  newLine.push(Number(turns[i].y));
}
```

You really should not use `for ... in` on arrays unless you **really** know that you need to do that.

Comment: i had no idea. bad habit i guess from Java programming.

Comment: @roguequery Java and JavaScript are almost completely different in everything but superficialities.